# Sending email via Ajax in Wordpress is not working

Tags: wordpress

This is a very mysterious problem for me. I confirmed that emails are being sent when I run site normally.

I used WP Forms and WooCommerce and they both send emails via Ajax. So I installed WP Mail Logging and I see emails are there under "successful". When I resend an email from that plugin it is working, I receive it. I tried to change my email via the WP admin panel just to confirm my theory and I got email confirmation.

I just can't figure out why emails are not received when sent via Ajax. Emails are not in spam/trash and I disabled caching.
I installed debug plugin, here are no errors, response is successful